# SQL Server 2012 - Best way to assign incrementing number for differing sets of records, from a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Any code warriors out there? :) I am kindly requesting for expertise in the best way (elegant?) of doing this. Cheers!

Booking system scenario. I basically need to add incoming new records to a `Master` bookings table.  The `Master` bookings table has a incrementing number (`Sequence_Number`), per set of bookings, per customer.

The Incoming New Bookings, if they match a customer already in the `MasterBookings`, need to have this `Sequence_Number` start from the last available number +1 and increment for all the new incoming bookings in that set. And this is per customer. There could new customers too in the new bookings which the `sequence_number` would have to start at 1.

e.g:-

`[MasterBookings]`:

```
CustomerNo   Sequence_Number     ExternalBookingID
---------------------------------------------------
0000001      1                   1234
0000001      2                   1285
0000001      3                   1324

0000002      1                   1534
0000002      2                   1585
0000002      3                   1524
0000002      4                   1534

0000003      1                   1734
0000003      13                  1785
```

`[NewBookings]`:

```
CustomerNo    ExternalBookingID
--------------------------------
0000001       8776
0000001       8787
0000002       8888
0000003       8998
0000004       9000
0000004       9001
0000004       9002
0000005       9211
```

I need to add the `[NewBookings]` into the `[MasterBookings]`, and they require the `sequence_number` field to be calculated and incremented

The final `[MasterBookings]` table after processing should contain this:

`[MasterBookings]`:

```
CustomerNo   Sequence_Number     ExternalBookingID
---------------------------------------------------
0000001      1                   1234
0000001      2                   1285
0000001      3                   1324
0000001      4                   8776
0000001      5                   8787

0000002      1                   1534
0000002      2                   1585
0000002      3                   1524
0000002      4                   1534
0000002      5                   8888

0000003      1                   1734
0000003      13                  1785
0000003      14                  8998

0000004      1                   9000
0000004      2                   9001
0000004      3                   9002

0000005      1                   9211
```

Thanks in advance.

Hello Guys, can I request a revision to the answer to to this scenario, as I have now been informed that the [NewBookingsTable] can contain previous bookings! So in essence, all bookings including historical and new ones can be in there.

Also, the [MasterBookings] can contain records that were not entered from the [NewBookingsTable] table.

Example, using the first Customer:-

e.g:-

`[MasterBookings]`:

```
CustomerNo   Sequence_Number     ExternalBookingID
---------------------------------------------------
0000001      1                   1234
0000001      2                   1285
0000001      3                   1324
0000001      4                   1367  <-- booking made from another source, not in the [NewBookings]
0000001      5                   1377  <-- booking made from another source ,not in the [NewBookings]
```

`[NewBookings]`:

```
CustomerNo    ExternalBookingID
--------------------------------

0000001       1234
0000001       1285
0000001       1324

0000001       8776      <-- a new booking not in the [MasterBookings]
0000001       8787      <-- a new booking not in the [MasterBookings]
```

I need to add the `[NewBookings]` into the `[MasterBookings]`, and they require the `sequence_number` field to be calculated and incremented

The final `[MasterBookings]` table after processing should contain this:

`[MasterBookings]`:

```
CustomerNo   Sequence_Number     ExternalBookingID
---------------------------------------------------
0000001      1                   1234
0000001      2                   1285
0000001      3                   1324

0000001      4                   1367
0000001      5                   1377

0000001      6                   8776
0000001      7                   8787
```

It still has to calculate per Set, per Customer.  I have only used the first CustomerNo as an example of this expanded scenario.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the row_number analytic function:

```
insert into MasterBookings (CustomerNo, Sequence_Number, ExternalBookingID)
select 
  CustomerNo,
  ExternalBookingID,
  row_number() over (partition by CustomerNo order by ExternalBookingID) +
  (
    select coalesce(max(Sequence_Number), 0)
    from MasterBookings
    where MasterBookings.CustomerNo = NewBookings.CustomerNo
  ) as Sequence_Number
from NewBookings;
```

The SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9aa9ef/7.

EDIT: You changed your request such as that NewBookings can contain bookins already present in MasterBookings. To solve this is very easy: Simply exclude records that exist in MasterBookings, using the EXISTS clause:

```
insert into MasterBookings (CustomerNo, ExternalBookingID, Sequence_Number)
select 
  CustomerNo,
  ExternalBookingID,
  row_number() over (partition by CustomerNo order by ExternalBookingID) +
  (
    select coalesce(max(Sequence_Number), 0)
    from MasterBookings
    where MasterBookings.CustomerNo = NewBookings.CustomerNo
  ) as Sequence_Number
from NewBookings
where not exists
(
  select *
  from MasterBookings
  where MasterBookings.CustomerNo = NewBookings.CustomerNo 
  and MasterBookings.ExternalBookingID = NewBookings.ExternalBookingID
);
```

Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ede49/2.

Comment: Nice, I did a similar one [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44c3c/4/0](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44c3c/4/0)

Comment: @TomT: Well done. A great alternative. About the same approach, but very readable, due to the WITH clauses and the pre-aggregation for the maximum sequence numbers.

Comment: Guys, I have revised the query as it has become more complex, can anyone revise the answer which was previously correct, taking into consideration the extra complexity I have introducted in the second section. Thanks!

Comment: This is very simple. All you need is an EXISTS clause. See my edited answer.